# How to include rows for absent data?

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I am using Firebird. I need the below result, but I don't get what I need. I tried the below query.

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pd.Date)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
  END AS "MONTH",
  Count(distinct pd.numbers) AS "Count"       
FROM Power_D pd 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pd.Date) = '2016' 
AND pd.Name = 'Test' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pd.Date)
```

For this query result below.

```
February    330
March       212
April       178
May         222
June        487
July        695
August      433
September   757
October     1307
November    321
December    143
```

But I need like below.

```
January     0
February    330
March       212
April       178
May         222
June        487
July        695
August      433
September   757
October     1307
November    321
December    143
```

Comment: If your question is about Firebird, why have you tagged it with Firebase, which is an entirely different product, from Google?

Comment: It looks like `Power_D` has no data from January 2016. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm certain that this identical question was asked a few days ago. Edited: I see it in your question history, but it looks like that was mysql. The same concept applies for any other RDBMS though. Generate a derived table (or actual date dimension table) that has each month you are interested in and then left join from that to your table and aggregate.

Comment: I moved my answer to your other question and marked this one as a duplicate. Please refrain from asking questions multiple times, and always make sure you tag the right DBMS so your question is seen by the right audience.